# How do I un-hide a photo in the iPhone iPhoto app?

Tags: iphone, mobile-iphoto

I mistakenly hit the 'x' button while editing a photo from the Camera Roll, and now I can't find the flagged menu to un-hide it as illustrated in the help.

Fortunately the photo is still in my Camera Roll, so how do I get it back into the iPhoto app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn your iPhone sideways and in the upper left hand corner hit the down arrow. Then select "Hidden Photos". This will show you a list of the photos you've hidden. Tap one, hit edit, and tap the "X" again to unhide it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can show the hidden photos by tapping in the upper left corner:

[image]